# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ClientsService (?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, nest

So I have a sample app im building in nest js and I hit an error on npm start

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ClientsService (?). Please make sure that the argument ClientModel at index [0] is available in the ClientsModule context.

So I have checked it over but cant seem to find why the error is happening

My client.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Client } from 'clients/interfaces/client.interface';
import { CreateClientDTO } from 'clients/dto/create-client.dto';


@Injectable()
export class ClientsService {
    constructor(@InjectModel('Client') private readonly clientModel: Model<Client>) { }

    // Get all clients
    async getClients(): Promise<Client[]> {
        const clients = await this.clientModel.find().exec();
        return clients
    }

    //Get single client
    async getClient(clientID: Promise<Client>) {
        const client = await this.clientModel
            .findById(clientID)
            .exec();
        return client;
    }

    //Add client
    async addClient(createClientDTO: CreateClientDTO): Promise<Client> {
        const newClient = await new this.clientModel(createClientDTO);
        return newClient.save()
    }
}
```

and my client.module.ts

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientsService } from './clients.service';
import { ClientsController } from './clients.controller';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ClientSchema } from 'clients/schemas/clients.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: 'Clients', schema: ClientSchema}])
  ],
  providers: [ClientsService],
  controllers: [ClientsController]
})
export class ClientsModule {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InjectModel` decorator expects to take the schema name of your entity.

So you tell the mongoose in `ClientsModule` that the schema name is `Clients`, but in `ClientsService` you try to inject the model with the schema name `Client`, which is different from the contract in the module.

```js
MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: 'Clients', schema: ClientSchema}])
```

```js
constructor(@InjectModel('Client') private readonly clientModel: Model<Client>) { }
```